# url rewriting to hide a directory

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My website directory contains 2 folders : `website1` and `website2`

So to access them:

- `http://www.example.com/website1`
- `http://www.example.com/website2`

I want to access them with these URLs:

- website1: `http://www.example.com`
- website2: `http://www.example.com/website2`

so I write this `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ website1/$1 [L]
```

This works well for `website1` but if I want to access `website2` it doesn't work (because it redirects to `http://www.example.com/website1/website2` I think)

How I can write this file to redirect only when URL is `http://www.example.com`?

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

- Create another `.htaccess` in the `/website2` and disable the rewrite engine:

  ```
  RewriteEngine Off
  ```

  This will prevent the mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` from running, so the request is not rewritten.

Or,

- Modify the existing mod_rewrite directives in the `.htaccess` file in the document root to exclude requests to the `/website2` subdirectory. For example:

  ```
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/website2
  RewriteRule (.*) website1/$1 [L]
  ```

  The `!` prefix on the *CondPattern* negates the regex, so it's only successful when the `REQUEST_URI` does not start with `/website2`.

  You could also combine this into a single directive, which is marginally more efficient:

  ```
  RewriteRule !^website2 website1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
  ```

  Note that the `REQUEST_URI` server variable already contains the slash prefix, so this must not be duplicated in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need htaccess for this. Put your website1 files in main root. Create a new folder and name it website2. Put website2 files in this new folder. I think this is what you want.